# One time login with user levels Android

Tags: android

this might be a duplicate question for you but i tried all of them and it still does nothing. I want my app to have a one time login and don't show the login page until the user logs out of the app and with also the user level. This is my code. thanks.

```
public class loginFragment extends Fragment implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
Button btnLogin;
EditText etUsername, etPassword;
TextView tvRegister;
CheckBox cbRemember;
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
boolean checkFlag;
int x = 0;

public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
String userId = "userID";

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

    etUsername = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etFirstname);
    etPassword = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    btnLogin = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    tvRegister = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvRegister);
    cbRemember = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cbRemember);
    cbRemember.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    checkFlag = cbRemember.isChecked();

    pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Login.conf", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = pref.edit();


    final String username = pref.getString("username", "");
    String password = pref.getString("password", "");


    HashMap postData = new HashMap();
    postData.put("username", username);
    postData.put("password", password);

    if (!username.equals("") && (!password.equals(""))) {
        PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(getActivity(), postData,
                new AsyncResponse() {
                    @Override
                    public void processFinish(String s) {

                        if (s.contains("renter")) {
                            Log.d(TAG, s);

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Renter Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), RenterTabs.class);
                            startActivity(in);

                            getActivity().finish();

                        } else if (s.contains("owner")) {
                            Log.d(TAG, s);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Owner Login Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), OwnerTabs.class);
                            startActivity(in);
                            getActivity().finish();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
        task1.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/authenticate.php");

    }

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            HashMap postData = new HashMap();


            postData.put("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
            postData.put("password", MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString()));

            PostResponseAsyncTask task1 = new PostResponseAsyncTask(getActivity(), postData,
                    new AsyncResponse() {
                        @Override
                        public void processFinish(String s) {
                            Log.d(TAG,s);
                            if (s.contains("renter")) {
                                if (checkFlag) {


                                    editor.putString("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
                                    editor.putString("password", MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString()));

                                    editor.apply();

                                    Log.d(TAG, pref.getString("password", ""));
                                }


                                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), RenterTabs.class);
                                startActivity(in);
                                getActivity().finish();

                            } else if (s.contains("owner")) {

                                if (checkFlag) {



                                    editor.putString("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
                                    editor.putString("password", MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString()));


                                    editor.apply();
                                }

                                editor.putString("username", etUsername.getText().toString());
                                editor.putString("password", MD5.encrypt(etPassword.getText().toString()));
                                editor.apply();

                                Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), OwnerTabs.class);
                                startActivity(in);
                                getActivity().finish();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Login Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                        }
                    });
            task1.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/authenticate.php");
        }
    });

    tvRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

return v;
}


@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    checkFlag = isChecked;
    Log.d(TAG, "checkflag: " + checkFlag);
}
}
```

Thank guys :)

Comment: Create ```NeedLogin``` variable with ```false``` value when user logged in and ```true``` when user loged out. Every time run app, check ```NeedLogin``` variable, if it ```false``` -> move to main page, if it ```true``` -> move to login page (or call login function automatic)

Comment: @DanhDC - thanks ill try. :)

Comment: @DanhDC - can you make a code where i will insert that methods sir? Thaaanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In your main activity class

```
public class Main_Activity extends FragmentActivity{

    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private Context ctx;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ctx = getApplicationContext();
        preferences = ctx.getSharedPreferences("MyPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Fragment fragment;
       //first time when run app, NeedLogin is null
        if (!preferences.getString("NeedLogin","").equals("false")){
            //Show your login page
            fragment = new loginFragment();
        }else{
            //Show your main content, after login successful
            fragment = new Home();
        }

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

    } 
}
```

- Then, in your login page, when login successful, update `NeedLogin` variable to `false` and save it to SharedPreference
- When user log out, update `NeedLogin` variable to `true` and save it to SharedPreference

Comment: Where Activity should I put this on the loginFragment or I will create another class? O.o

Comment: In your main activity, use my example code, and you can cont. use your ```loginFragment``` class, just remember update ```NeedLogin``` after login success.